# Trying to call save method from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to update the number of holiday days an employee has when they book a holiday. I'm trying to save the employee from the model that doesn't seem to be working, the holiday creates perfectly otherwise. I had it working before but must've changed something by mistake as no matter what I do I cant get it back working. Any Ideas?

Holidays Controller

```
def create
  @holiday = Holiday.new(holiday_params)
  @holiday.employee_id = current_employee.id

  if(Holiday.pastHol(@holiday))
    if(Holiday.h_authorize(current_employee, @holiday))
      if(Holiday.update_holidays(current_employee,@holiday))
        respond_to do |format|
          if @holiday.save
            format.html {  redirect_to action: "index", notice: 'holiday accecpted' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @holiday }
          end
        end
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to action: "index", notice: 'holiday declined' }
          format.json { render json: @holiday.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to action: "index", notice: "Already on Hols" }
        format.json { render json: @holiday.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to action: "index", notice: "Date error" }
      format.json { render json: @holiday.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Holiday Model

```
scope :update_holidays, lambda{ |q| where("amount > ?", q) }
scope :proj_authorize, lambda{ |q| where("amount > ?", q) }

def self.update_holidays(employee, holiday)
  employee.DaysHolidays == employee.DaysHolidays - (holiday.endDate - holiday.startDate ) - 1

  if (employee.DaysHolidays > 0)
    employee.save
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Holiday Index

```
<%= form_for(@holiday) do |f| %>
  <%= errors_for(@holiday) %>

  <h3>Holiday Request</h3>

  <%= current_employee.name %> , you have <%= current_employee.DaysHolidays %> holiday days remaining.<br><br>

  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :startDate %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :startDate , id: :datepicker,  placeholder: "Start Date" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :endDate %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :endDate , id: :datepicker1,  placeholder: "End Date" %>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit 'Request Holiday', :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace `save` with `save!` at all places and you will see an exception if a validation fails

Comment: Thanks, It's not saving because a password can't be blank, is there any way to ignore this field or just update the number of days holidays?

Comment: Is this error on some `Employee` object? Are you creating an `Employee` object at the same time when creating a `Holiday`?

Comment: Please post your `employee.rb` so that we can see the logic that's validating the password. Are you using devise?

Comment: I managed to find the issue, I just removed some of my password validation in the employee.rb and it worked fine, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you've already found the answer to your question, but I really wanted to refactor a bit your controller. While I highly advise you move your `if` cases to a service class or underlying approach probably should be different but without other information, I can do so much. Here is a slight refactor while keeping everything in the controller:

```
def create
  @holiday = Holiday.new(holiday_params)
  @holiday.employee_id = current_employee.id
  notice = 
    if(Holiday.pastHol(@holiday))
      if(Holiday.h_authorize(current_employee, @holiday))
        if(Holiday.update_holidays(current_employee, @holiday))
          "holiday accepted"
        else
          "holiday declined"
        end
      else
        "Already on Hols"
      end
    else
      "Date error"
    end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to action: "index", notice }
    if @holiday.save
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @holiday }
    else
      format.json { render json: @holiday.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```